# Pentaho Report Designer mySQl query select

Tags: php, mysql, database, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Using Pentaho Report Designer, I can set up a data source to connect to my MySQL database which is hosted locally using phpmyadmin.

Testing the connection works, pulling in variables for setting up queries works, running previews of said queries displays the correct output, but I can not add any db fields into the report. Dragging/Dropping from the data pane simply won't work.

Anyone any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried checking "Select fields" option in the database query in the data section (by right clicking on the db query) ?

Comment: Rishu, when right clicking on the desired query, there is no "Select Fields" option, only "select query, edit query, convert to table etc"

Selecting "Select Query", all it does is change the query icon from a bullet point to a folder.. still unable to move/use it =/

Comment: Sorry my bad ... its "Select Query" .. ideally what is does is that it enables the fields to be draggable.. !! .. it would be really helpful if you can share ur prpt.?

Comment: What would you like me to share? I'm very new to pentaho so I'm quite lost right now.

Comment: Can you share me the report which you have created?

Comment: I can not, there is no report to share. I'm able to write queries int he query designer and pull in data from mysql db, when i preview the query i am shown a working, functional preview. but when i am completely unable to move these into my blank report. It just wont allow me :s

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for anyone in the future who may have the same problem. I solved it by adding a "Limit" in the query editor.

Example:

SELECT
     `batchjobs`.`name`,
     `batchjob_params`.`format`,
     `batchjob_params`.`notes`
FROM
     `batchjobs`,
     `batchjob_params` LIMIT 1

Without the "LIMIT 1", the query contents would not appear for selection in the report designer!

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment here that if you are using a newer version of MySQL, then you might want to check the driver and make sure it's compatible with the MySQL version.  i.e. Using an older JDBC MySQL driver, a connection to a MySQL 5.1 server works fine, but connecting to a MySQL 5.6 server does not return the fields for the query.  Adding a LIMIT to the query is a work around, but updating the driver would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

ideally there are two possible ways of selecting/Dragging the field in the report designer.

Step 1 :  Select the Database Query and right click on it to select "SELECT QUERY" option. This brings down a list of columns. This makes the query fields draggable on the report.

Step 2 : Try to use the left panel. There you will find "text-field" or "number-field". Drag these labels on the report. Once you have done it, click on the field and you will be given an option to select the fields. You can select any of the fields as per the requirement.
If it is not available, then you might have to enable the STEP I and then try STEP II.

Try any of the steps above. Hoping this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Tried, but didnt work. The only fields that are available for selection are the standard fields from the "Environment" section of the Data tab, even when I select the query like you said. 

there must be a problem with the db connection? the db is made of sql and .net, both outdated, so no doubt there are many conflictions getting in the way.

Comment: Possible .. But it would have thrown error while previewing even if ther is a version conflict.., anyways it would be better if we can do a check on the version conflict of both pentaho and sql server!!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue, what i did was, put quotes around the parameters that were passed in the query in the kettle transformation from your report. Strange but i does solved the issue.